# Java GUI appearance

Tags: java, user-interface

I am working in java during  my semester break and came across a question. I have a gui window that is used to select a file from a directory on my computer. This works fine however the gui itself looks like a very old version of windows. I thought that the GUI took on the look of the windows for the current OS. Is it how I am formating the GUI.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code in the main method:

```
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

it will give to your application the default system look.